# iTunes Artwork images type removal?

Tags: ios, macos, itunesartwork

I have an existing **iTunesArtwork** image

To modify the image I've converted it to **png** image

As I read that the iTunes artwork is nothing 
but a png image without png extension

so I added a png extension and it became png image then I modified the image 
then I removed the png extension and its not working as it supposed to be.

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above steps are correct for window environment but in mac you have to follow the below steps/

> Right click on the image -> Choose GetInfo -> Choose Name & extension
>   -> remove the extension.png -> close the GetInfo Box -> Give yes when prompted to save.

This is the way to remove or change extension in Mac

Hope this helps